Preventing resizable flexbox images getting cut off by boundaries of box or browser window
I am trying to lay out pairs of images horizontally next to one another such such that:

both images take up roughly the same area regardless of their relative aspect ratios
each image fits vertically within the viewport
the images side by side fit horizontally within the viewport

I am very close with the following layout, but the images will disappear off the left and right of the page when the viewport has certain shapes and sizes.
<!doctype html>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<style>
@import url('reset.css'); /* https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ */
:root {
    background-color: oklch(95.25% 0.0187 235.01);
}
.diptych-area {
    display: flex;
    width: min(90vh, 100vw);
    height: 90vh;
    margin: auto;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    container-type: size;

    figure {
        &.left {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: end;
            flex-basis: calc((var(--left-aspect-ratio) / (var(--left-aspect-ratio) + var(--right-aspect-ratio))) * 100vw); }
        &.right {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: start;
            flex-basis: calc((var(--right-aspect-ratio) / (var(--left-aspect-ratio) + var(--right-aspect-ratio))) * 100vw); }
        box-sizing: border-box;
        img {
            max-height: 100cqh; } } }

figure {
    flex-basis: content;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 1rem;
    scroll-snap-align: center;

    & img {
        display: block;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        max-height: 80vh;
        max-width: min(100vh, 100cqw);
        border: 24px solid white; }
</style>

<p>test 1 2 3

<div class=diptych-area style="--left-aspect-ratio: 0.6667; --right-aspect-ratio: 1.5;">
  <figure class=left>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/67/Escaleras_a_la_Catedral_--_2023_--_Burgos%2C_Castilla_y_León%2C_España.jpg/1365px-Escaleras_a_la_Catedral_--_2023_--_Burgos%2C_Castilla_y_León%2C_España.jpg">
  </figure>
  <figure class=right>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/68/Himalayas%2C_Cholatse%2C_Nepal.jpg/1280px-Himalayas%2C_Cholatse%2C_Nepal.jpg">
  </figure>
</div>

<p>test 1 2 3

<div class=diptych-area style="--left-aspect-ratio: 0.6667; --right-aspect-ratio: 0.6667;">
  <figure class=left>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8d/Фрагмент_церкви._Дошки_оббивки.jpg/682px-Фрагмент_церкви._Дошки_оббивки.jpg">
  </figure>
  <figure class=right>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/19/Crack_climbing_in_Indian_Creek%2C_Utah.jpg/681px-Crack_climbing_in_Indian_Creek%2C_Utah.jpg">
  </figure>
</div>

<p>test 1 2 3

<div class=diptych-area style="--left-aspect-ratio: 1.2; --right-aspect-ratio: 0.8;">
  <figure class=left>
    <div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bb/Flussregenpfeifer_im_flachen_Wasser_01.jpg/1219px-Flussregenpfeifer_im_flachen_Wasser_01.jpg"></div>
  </figure>
  <figure class=right>
    <div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/21/Galería_Sciarra%2C_Roma%2C_Italia%2C_2022-09-16%2C_DD_117-119.jpg/818px-Galería_Sciarra%2C_Roma%2C_Italia%2C_2022-09-16%2C_DD_117-119.jpg"></div>
  </figure>
</div>

At this window size things are okay:

but when resized the photos do not get smaller to fulfill the third condition:

I can’t work out how to get the pictures to shrink appropriately according to the horizontal size of the viewport.


I think you should try using % with image width, so whenever your screen size is reduced, the images can adapt to the new size of the screen.

Another reason can be that when you reduce the screen size, some portion of image got disappeared because the width of image is more than the width of the screen size. To solve this, you have to use responsive media queries.


